# Random de 10 Segundos

Tags: c#

Tengo una inquietante y es de cómo puedo hacer para que un evento random dure 10 segundos, lo que sucede es que estoy desarrollando una tómbola en c# y al momento de crear los números al azar en mis texboxs sólo me los genera una única vez. Este es el Código que utilizo para generar el random en un button, Al final los numeros tiene que hacer un random parecido a un juego de loteria:

```
            Random random1 = new Random();
            txtP1.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(1, 9));
            txtP2.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
            txtP3.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
            txtP4.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
            txtP5.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
            txtP6.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
            txtP7.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
            txtP8.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
            txtP9.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
            txtP10.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
```

Comment: hola. a que te referis con que dure diez segundos?? cambiar los numeros que salen durante 10 segundos?

Comment: Exactamente que durante 10 segundos cambien los numeros

Comment: Un refresh no alcanza @pikoh?

Comment: Un `Application.DoEvents()` en tu respuesta serviría @gbianchi,pero es mejor poner tu codigo en un backgroundworker o un task,aunque hay q tener cuidado pq desde ese hilo no se pueden modificar los textboxes

Comment: Habria q verificar el thread original o generar eventos para el refresh. Yo iria por lo simple no se si tiene sentido hacer tanto lio. O usan un timer cada 500 ms que va a terminar haciendo el refresh automaticamente

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razon, posiblemente un timer es la solución mas sencilla ;)

Comment: y como empleo ese timer sin tener que mover mis random  de cada uno de mis textboxes al evento tick del timer @gbianchi

Comment: Como q moverlos? No tenes todo el codigo junto?

Comment: otra cuestion es que en el timer al pasar los 10  seg, se puede detener automaticamente o hay que usar a fuerzas el timer.stop

Comment: @gbianchi mis random los tengo en un button no en un evento timer y hasta donde entiendo para que se puedan visualizar los numero durante los 10 segundos tendira que moverlos al evento tick del timer, o estoy mal

Comment: Exactamente.... y cual es el problema?

Comment: osea que tengo una variable que me almacena el resultado de los textboxs al finlizar el random y al mover los randoms al evento tick del timer dicha variable no me captura los resultados de mis texbox

Answer (score 1):

Podes incluir tu codigo dentro de un ciclo while que cuente los segundos hasta diez.

```
System.DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
Random random1 = new Random();
while (dt >= DateTime.Now)
{
    txtP1.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(1, 9));
    txtP2.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
    txtP3.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
    txtP4.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
    txtP5.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
    txtP6.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
    txtP7.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
    txtP8.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
    txtP9.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
    txtP10.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
}
```

EDICION 1:

Dado que no era lo que querias exactamente, la nueva recomendación es que uses un timer en tu formulario, y lo pongas para que ejecute el evento tick cada 500 ms.

Luego de ello, en el evento tick deberias hacer:

```
txtP1.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(1, 9));
txtP2.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
txtP3.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
txtP4.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
txtP5.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
txtP6.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
txtP7.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
txtP8.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
txtP9.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
txtP10.Text = Convert.ToString(random1.Next(0, 9));
```

También deberías saber cuando parar... para eso podrías contar 20 ejecuciones de este evento.. o tomar el tiempo desde el primer evento tick hasta el ultimo. o Tener otro timer separado que se ejecute a los 10 segundos y pare este.

Comment: Oye y no habra manera de añadir un timer para que el randon se muestre durante esos 10 segundos en mis textboxs, lo que sucede es que con este fragmento de codigo los numeros aparecen hasta los diez segundos, en si lo que quiero es que durante diez segundos este cambiando los numeros de los textboxs y al llegar a los diez segundos se detenga, Gracias por tu valiosa ayuda

Comment: no entiendo.. esto va cambiando numeros durante 10 segundos... que queres que se muestre el tiempo tambien?

Comment: si va cambiando numeros durante 10 segundos, lo que quiero que me muestre unicamente son los numeros que van cambiando

Comment: y que otras cosas se muestran??? no estaria entendiendo que estas buscando..podes mostrar algun ejemplo?

Comment: Osea, ¿Si el numero actual del texto es igual al del nuevo no se cambie?

Comment: Para darte cuenta deberías ir cambiando el color del texto, me imagino? además quieres que cambie en intervalos de 1 segundo? ósea que solo cambie 10 veces 1 vez por segundo hasta llegar a los 10 segundos?